# How SVUnit has been used?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm looking for reasons to use SVUnit in my projects. As a software engineer I used to write tests before the production code. However, I don't see so much adoption of this initiative. Why? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention you used to be a software engineer, I guess you don't need to be lectured on why unit testing is good or why TDD makes sense. Since testbenches are very much akin to software, this means that a lot of software development best practices can be carried over to testbench development, unit testing being one of them.

The fact that it hasn't seen much adoption yet shouldn't be a reason not to use something.

I've written about SVUnit here: http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2014/05/a-quick-look-at-svunit.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you recommend any good references to start with? The demo series in AgileSoc page is outdated and this make me feel a little suspicious about it.

Comment: That's something that needs looking at for sure, but unfortunately there aren't many resources out there yet. I've got some code examples up on my site where I use unit testing, but I can't point you to any exact post unfortunately.You'll need to have a look at the repo yourself. Another thing I can think of is this page I wrote for one of our projects: https://github.com/Freecellera/freecellera-uvm/wiki/UVM-Bug-Blitz---bug-fix-example

Comment: Ok. Thank you Tudor! I'll give it a try but this lack of information is a big problem. :(

Comment: If you've used other xUnit frameworks, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language can be interfaced to SystemVerilog by Direct Programming Interface.

By referring quote from Sectioin 35.2 of [IEEE 1800 - 2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) it is possible but adopting to it to the environment is based on the programmers understanding of the calls and routines of the language.

> DPI is an interface between SystemVerilog and a foreign programming
>   language. It consists of two separate layers: the SystemVerilog layer
>   and a foreign language layer. Both sides of DPI are fully isolated.
>   Which programming language is actually used as the foreign language is
>   transparent and irrelevant for the SystemVerilog side of this
>   interface.

Comment: @Tudor Thanks for pointing, when I went through it, it seems like a framework which was similar to scoreboard framework